# java string validation for 3 choices

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a user validation for multiple choices using a while loop and If the user doesn't match the choices then the program has to terminate. This is what I got so far

```
  while(input!="air" || input!="water" || input!="steel"){
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

I would prefer to do exceptions, but my professor is strictly against using it for this assignment. I really want to grow as a programmer so any advice, tips and tricks are welcomed, thank you all for trying to help me out.

Comment: If the program should exit in case of a wrong input instead of asking for another one there is no point in using a `while` loop.

Comment: Then what would you suggest I use instead??

Comment: Well, the program should exit `if` a condition is true ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change it as

```
while(!input.equals("air") && !input.equals("water") && !input.equals("steel")){
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Or

```
while(!(input.equals("air") || input.equals("water") || input.equals("steel"))){
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: When would that condition ever be `false` ?

Comment: That only solves one problem. Can you provide any `input` for which condition in `while` will be evaluated as `false`? Also what about first instruction in that loop. Does it make sense to loop it?

Comment: @Pshemo  I overlooked that aspect! Just updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @sinclair Just updated the answer. Thanks!